# Django Site with Country Map

Tags: django

I have a site-project that needs to be done in Django. I have to a country for example the map of Germany and on that map, when the user is moving the mouse over a region like Bavaria to show him the cities of that region. While clicking on a city, i need some page/list to be displayed with population, some authorities numbers etc. Can someone pls advise. I found something made in JavaScript that has what i want, without the clicking event for each region/city etc. https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Comment: Advise about what? The leafletjs examples seem to be doing everything you are looking for,

Comment: I dont knoe js and to do a site with js

Comment: Why do you tag the question with Django if your problem is JS related?

Comment: because i need advise on how this from js can be made in django. i don't know how this can be done with django.

Comment: @Cohen Django is backend code, JavaScript is frontend code in the case of `leafletjs`; these two complement each other, they cannot replace one another. You can look into [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to build a REST service that serves the data for your frontend JS.

Comment: you can use plotly to do such things in pure python.
https://plot.ly/python/choropleth-maps/

Comment: i saw that, but they serve only US. For other non US countries, they did made it extremely hard to draw the countries.